# What's the meaning of the word "tad"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I always see the word in sentence like, "it's a tad faser".
Or people say "tad", as if they are frustrated.
So, what's the meaning of the word? When to use it?

Comment: Where did you look it up?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means a little bit.  Per the OED:

> A small amount; freq. used *advb*. in the expression **a tad**, a little, slightly.
>
> - 1940 Amer. Speech XV. 448/1 ― Tad, a very small amount. ‘I want to borrow a tad of salt.’
> - 1969 L. Michaels Going Places 159, ― I tried to smile. ‘You come back later, baby. I’m a tad indisposed.’
> - 1976 Time 27 Sept. 39/2 ― ‘Pull ’er up a tad, please, mister,’ said the nonchalant teen-ager pumping gas.
> - 1977 Time 14 Mar. 28/3 ― White House watchers also think they can glimpse a tad of arrogance showing through the good ole boy pose.
> - 1977 Globe & Mail (Toronto) 15 Dec. 8/2 ― Things are a tad hectic.
> - 1979 D. Anthony Long Hard Cure xv. 116 ― Why don’t we sit here on the veranda? There’s a tad of breeze.
> - 1980 N.Y. Times 12 Aug. a18/1 ― The Mayor’s pitch is a tad exaggerated both on the law’s certainty and on the roominess of New York’s prisons.

You can use it wherever you would use *a little* or *a bit*:

- I’m a tad tired of the same old supper every night.
- Q: You tired yet?  A: Yeah, a tad.
- Personally, I’m a tad unclear on how something that hasn't even been out for a full week already counts as “old”.
- That sounds a tad off to me.

Comment: Nice answer.  It's worth noting that I've never heard, "It's tad" before in my life. Not sure where OP got that one.

Comment: Also, since tad also means 'little', it's also used as: "I'm running a tad bit late for the dinner, honey."

Comment: @Caffeine Never heard that. "Running a tad late," yes, but never *tad* **and** *bit* together.

Comment: I read it in en email from my college's Program Cordinator. I guess it's not used as such formally. Here's what google says:

http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/01/tad.html

Comment: I agree with Andrew Leach. I have never heard *tad* and *bit* used together, and this is supported by [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tad%2Ctad+bit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3, BNC (48 *tad*; 0 *tad bit*), and COCA (1412 *tad*; 14 *tad bit*).

Comment: FWIW, I use "a tad" all the time in _spoken_ English (probably too much). I think of it as slang. It is certainly not formal. I never use _tad_ and _bit_ together. @Jim "It's tad" -> "It's **a** tad".